# rails remote form and jquery

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

use rails 4.2.6, coffee-rails 4.1.0, jquery-rails 4.1.1.
have a form with remote: true

my .slim view

```
div class="throughputs_update"
  = form_tag("/proxyz/throughputs/#{host['throughputs'][proxy_type]['id']}", method: :put, remote: true) do
    div class="row"
      div class="col-xs-6"
        div class="input-group"
          = number_field_tag :amount, host['throughputs'][proxy_type]['amount'], min: 0, class: "form-control"
          span class="input-group-btn"
            = button_tag nil, type:"submit", class:"btn btn-default"
              span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
```

with html:

```
<div class="throughputs_update">
  <form action="/proxyz/throughputs/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" value="1" min="0" class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
              </span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

in .coffee

```
ready = ->
  console.log "first"
    jQuery ->
    $(document)
      .on "ajax:success", ".throughputs_update", ->
        console.log "ajax:success"
      .on "ajax:complete", ".throughputs_update", ->
        console.log "ajax:complete"
      .ajaxSend ->
        console.log "ajax send"
      .ready ->
        console.log "ready!"

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

in my controller:

```
  def update
    ...
    render json: @host, status: :ok
  end
```

After submitting the form, it does not work, none of the functions. The only console.log:

```
first
ready!
```

and no errors.
In rails console:

```
Started PUT "/proxyz/throughputs/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-26 12:18:30 +0300
Processing by Proxyz::ThroughputsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "amount"=>"1", "button"=>"", "id"=>"3"}
...
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I think that binding your `.on "ajax:success"` to the div (`".throughputs_update"`) that's wrapping the form is what's going wrong. I bet if you took out the `".throughputs_update"` and just had `.on "ajax:success" ->` that it would work. Or if you really wanted bind to that form you could use and on click event bound to the button tag. If you provided a little more detail about what you want to do when the form is submitted someone may be able to describe a good way to do it.

Comment: If you mean the following code: ready = ->
 jQuery ->
    $(document)
      .on "ajax:success", ->
        console.log "ajax:success"
      .on "ajax:complete", ->
        console.log "ajax:complete"
      .ajaxSend ->
        console.log "ajax send"
      .ready ->
        console.log "ready!"

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready) - that is unfortunately the result is the same. My goal - it is depending on the result of the query to execute actions